# Updates problem giving a PPA not found error

Tags: nvidia, ppa

I am on Ubuntu 14.04 and it always show me the little icon for updates, I do it and every time it show me this message :

```
W:Failed to fetch (http)://ppa.launchpad.net/c-korn/ppa/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/source/Sources 404 Not Found ,
W:Failed to fetch (http)://ppa.launchpad.net/c-korn/ppa/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages 404 Not Found ,
W:Failed to fetch (http)://ppa.launchpad.net/c-korn/ppa/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages 404 Not Found ,      
E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I googled and didn't find any "accurate" solution for this error, do you think is my nvidia driver the problemes ( I use the nvidia driver giving in software and updates : proprietary, tested) ? Because I have some little problems to make my Nvidia drivers work well.

Comment: And what is that `c-korn` ppa? It probably does not exist. Just remove that ppa.

Comment: @Pilot6 : I tryed to find those PPA to remove them and can't find :/

Comment: Where did you look for it?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `ls /etc/apt/sources.list.d` terminal command.

Comment: I try to search in Ubuntu synaptic, and also I found out about the "ls /etc/apt/sources.list.d" and they were saying to add a "#" before the one I wanted to "disable" and still didn't find it. I am currently at work but I will add it when back home :) also thank you for trying to help me !

Answer (score 3):

This is not the nvidia drivers - someone (you?) has added a PPA for the purpose of installing some software.  The PPA in question however, does not support Ubuntu 14, only Ubuntu 16.

Open `Software & Updates`, look for a line similar to `http://ppa:launchpad.net/c-korn...` and uncheck the line.   After that, you should be fine.